# Looking To Download Entire Gmail Account Into Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

Can anyone help me achieve this.

I am looking to download the entire history of my gmail account into Outlook.

I have managed to do this previously (Even for emails I had deleted from the Gmail server) so I do know it is possible.

However at the moment, all I seem able to do is download the entire amount of emails presently in the gmail account, ie not with the deleted ones.

Has anyone any advise on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. In outlook create a PST file, or have any **other** account available (IMAP, POP3, ...)
2. Grab some email and drop it into e.g. the (new) Inbox of the account at 1.
3. Wait for the copy or move to finish.

In my opinion it is easier to see that all has been transferred if you **move** the items - hold ALT(?) as you drop the items.

Comment: Please explain how that moves the gmail deleted items.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I'm not acquainted enough with gmail to tell. If the deleted items are visible though; I'd expect there be no difference - they should be movable in the same manner. Might be you need to "undelete" them first though - I'd suggest to do that after moving out the inbox content first.